# Как обойти блокировку по IP Python?

Tags: python, ip, proxy

Python Код:

```
requests.get(f"https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active={adress}&n=1")
```

после 400 запросов получает бан по ip, пробовал с прокси (которое добывает скрипт с сайта: https://www.proxy-list.download/api/v1/get?type=https) не работает. Как обойти блокировку без ожидания.

Comment: Как часто Вы делаете запросы?

Comment: Примерно 4 запроса в секунду.

Comment: Зачем так быстро? Попробуйте ограничить до 1 запроса в 10 секунд. И не нужно будет использовать прокси. Здесь написано про частоту запросов https://www.blockchain.com/ru/api/q

Comment: В этом и проблема, нельзя ограничивать скорость.